# How can I get the user IDs who checked in my Facebook page by using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to find a description on the web, but I couldn't find how to do that.
I want to know who checked in our page, and use the photo data that they post with their checkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible, because you need those people's permissions to get access to their personal data.

Have a look at:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.2

Comment: If I get that Is it possible?